# Is it possible to power off the device using adb?

Tags: adb, power-on

Is there any way (command/option) to power-off the device using `adb` command?

Comment: @AndrewT. This question does not solve my problem. I tried `reboot -p`--->`Operation not permitted`. Other commands returns `not found`.  On the other hand, all of those commands are shell commands that are executed on the device, But I am looking for a command such as `adb reboot -s` or `adb shutdown` that is entered on PC command line.

Comment: Still, it's a duplicate of that question. It's an unfortunate situation that you still can't comment on other post/put bounty, but since you've tried it, *incorporate the info you wrote on comment to the question*. I also tried it just now, and it also doesn't work. Somehow I suspect there is a change in adb.exe between SDK.

Comment: Try "adb shell" and see if device has "shutdown" command (it should be under /system/bin/). If shutdown binary is there, then type "shutdown" command should work